# Скомпилировать dll в Сlion под ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, dll

Как скомпилировать dll в Сlion под ubuntu, компилятор g++, сборщик Cmake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какая связь между *dll* и *Ubuntu* ?!
У Вас что - кросс-компиляция предполагается?
Или Вы имеете в виду *so* ?

Если всё-таки речь идёт о создании разделяемой библиотеки для *Linux* (любого, а не только *Ubuntu*) с помощью *cmake*, то опять-же, библиотеку создаёт не *cmake* (и уж тем более - не *Clion*) а линкер. Задание линкеру, на создание разделяемой библиотеки, которое будет выполнять *cmake* выглядит приблизительно так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(my_so)

# Собираем библиотеку

add_library(my_so SHARED
   src1.cpp
   src2.cpp
   . . .
   srcN.cpp
)
```

Есть очень хорошая книжка про *cmake*: "СИСТЕМА ПОСТРОЕНИЯ ПРОЕКТОВ CMAKE", Д. В. ДУБРОВ

Comment: Я сижу под Ubuntu а необходимо написать небольшую прослойку для mql4, что бы научить его работать с rabbitmq. Что бы не ставить  windows от этого вытекает такой вопрос.

Comment: @AlexToimy "написать небольшую прослойку для mql4" - Вы имеете в виду вот это : (https://book.mql4.com/intro) ? Но, насколько я понял, есть версия и для Люниха... Или надо ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО для виндовоза сделать из люниха?  Честно говоря, первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой задачей. Мне кажется, проще всего поставить виртуальную машину  и взгромоздить туда виндовозный компилятор...

Comment: да надо сделать под windows, видимо так и придется сделать, думал мб есть какой то способ это сделать из под linux